# US citizen applying for UK settlement visa/entry (3 part question)

Tags: us-citizens, uk-citizens

Background: My husband is a UK citizen (by birth, born, raised, etc). We have 3 children together. We all lived together in the US. Recently (May2017) we went to visit family in the UK. Sometime in the summer we decided that moving there was the next option for our family (we'd talked  about it more and more). We have no true ties any longer to the US with regard to family and he has an ailing parent that the siblings are all taking turns caring for. Since I came over as a visitor, I understood I had no right to stay.  So i went back to the states to finalize things, close up shop so to speak. However, he stayed with our children and we were told to obtain British passports as they are British because their father is. They all go to school in the UK now with no complications according to the magistrate and we're working on me.

1. I've recently (yesterday) applied and submitted and paid for my settlement visa. In printing out the forms to be submitted I noticed a clerical error. It's minor but could be a big deal as it refers to income. Every reference we'd seen refers to ANNUAL income... but here it apparently did MONTHLY and I didn't catch it. Obviously, if my annual income was in fact my monthly I probably wouldn't even sweat it. But as I don't make 20k per month, this is not the case. Can I make a pen and ink correction and include an explanatory letter (along with supporting documentation)? Or do i risk refusal and in turn, my fee? I ask because if I cancel my application it says it takes up to 90 days for a refund. I miss my family. I'm trying not to drag this out further. And obviously don't have the money to just cancel it, repay now and then wait on the refund to get back eventually.
2. I'm a self-employed freelance graphic designer. It only asks for my husband's income for the financial requirement. By himself he doesn't make enough to support all of us. But with my income we do with no issues. We're married and have shared a household so everything had been together. Am I missing an option where I get to enter MY income? *note, I have proof (contracts, bank statement, etc) that can prove my income.
3. If this is denied or we decide to postpone the application (i.e. I cancel it and wait on the refund) can I still go back over as a visitor? I'd like to see my family at least for Christmas. I know there are things like showing proof of return ticket and what not.